# How to pull data from Database in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to display the start and end date from the database in a label but for now, I'm able to pull the record id, I'm not how I would pull the start and end date instead of the record id. What I have so far.

```
<label for="Record">Record</label>
                        <select name="record">
                            {%for record in records %}
                                <option value="{{record.recordid}}">{{ record }}</option>
                            {%endfor %}
                        </select>
```

Comment: What are the fields named in the record?  What format do you want to display the dates?  What does your entity look like?  etc.

Comment: Using a date inside an option `value` would be a very bad idea as you may be unable to retrieve this single record only using the dates

Comment: recordId, startDate, endDate. it would just pull it from the database so the format that's in the database. Format: 2017-09-21

Comment: How would I get it as a select option, like drop down of all the dates in the database.

Comment: Try `{{ record.startDate|date('Y-m-d') }}`

Comment: did not get any results, it was blank. and it's both the end date and start date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <label for="Record">Record</label>
                    <select name="record">
                        {%for record in records %}
                            <option value="{{record.recordid}}">{{ 
  record.startDate }} -- {{ record.endDate }}
  </option>
                        {%endfor %}
                    </select>
```

Comment: But what if you wanted that to show everywhere, like on the form